Powershell script for adding registry keys inconsistent if there is an absence of "Start-Sleep" in the script
I am  trying to create a powershell script that includes the addition of two registry values. When the script is executed without adding a "Start-Sleep" of 5 seconds between the "set item property" of two registry values, it is not consistent. Most of the time, the "NoAutoUpdate" registry value is not added.
Is there any alternative to "Start-Sleep"? To make the script execution consistent?
    $filesToCopy = ""
        
    foreach ($file in $filesToCopy) {
    Copy-Item -Path $file.Source -Destination $file.Destination -Recurse -Force
    }
    
    #AppLocker
    $registryPath = "Registry::HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AppIDSvc"   
    $name = "Start"
    $value = "2"
    $filename = "\Rules.xml"   
    $CertName = "\x.cer"
    $invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
    $directorypath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path
    $Certpath = $directorypath + $CertName  
    $filepath = $directorypath + $filename    
    
    # Add certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store
    Set-Location -Path cert:\LocalMachine\Root   
    Import-Certificate -Filepath $Certpath   
    
    Write-Host "AppLocker enabled and rules created successfully." 
     
    # Check if the Application Identity service is running
    $serviceStatus = Get-Service -Name "AppIDSvc"
    if ($serviceStatus.Status -eq 'Running') {
        Write-Host "Application Identity service is running already."
    } else {
        # Set the Application Identity service to start automatically
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value
        Write-Host "Application Identity service is starting. System will reboot." 
        # Restart the computer
        shutdown /r  
    }
    
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    # Ensure the registry path exists and create it if it does not exist
    $regPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
    if (-not (Test-Path $regPath)) {
        New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate" -Name "AU" -Force
    }

    # Add Registry key to stop Windows Auto Updates
    try {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name NoAutoUpdate -Value 1 -Type DWord -Force
        Write-Output "NoAutoUpdate registry key created successfully."
    } catch {
        Write-Output "Failed to create NoAutoUpdate registry key: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
   } 
 
   finally {  
    # Any cleanup code can go here if necessary
   }


[1] $registryPath = "Registry::HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AppIDSvc" should be Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AppIDSvc or use the built-in HKLM: PSDrive: HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AppIDSvc
[2] you do a shutdown /r after the first part and expect the script to go on with the remaining part of the script..
[3] you have one closing curly brace too many after the catch{..} block, so now the finally{..} is not at the same level. (you could improve those mistakes by indenting your code better)
